# Question about the proof of Theorem D.5, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by Lee

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem from Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds":

[image]

The following statement is in the proof:
[image]

***Question:*** What I don't see is how $\frac{2\epsilon e^{CT}}{E}\cdot(e^{ET}-1)$ can be made as small as desired by choosing $h$ and $\tilde{h}$ sufficiently small. How does the expression depend on $h$ and $\tilde{h}$? To me it looks like an upper bound.

**The only idea I have is the following:**

There is the following statement
[image]
Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k>\frac{2e^{CT}}{E}\cdot(e^{ET}-1)$ and $\tilde{\epsilon}:=\frac{\epsilon}{k}$,  and $\epsilon$ as above.
By the above statement I can find a $\tilde{\delta}$ such that $|y_{1}-y_{2}|<\tilde{\delta}$ implies
\begin{align}
|\frac{\partial V^{i}}{\partial y^{k}}(y_{1})-\frac{\partial V^{i}}{\partial y^{k}}(y_{2})|<\tilde{\epsilon}=\frac{\epsilon}{k}
\end{align}

Now the book says

[image]
I would instead say "Suppose that $h$ and $\tilde{h}$ are both less than $\frac{\tilde{\delta} e^{-CT}}{n}$".

From here on I would proceed exactly as in the book to end up with the inequality
\begin{align}
|\Delta_{h}(t,x)-\Delta_{\tilde{h}}(t,x)|\leq...\leq\frac{2\tilde{\epsilon} e^{CT}}{E}\cdot(e^{ET}-1)=\frac{2\epsilon e^{CT}}{k\cdot E}\cdot(e^{ET}-1)<\epsilon
\end{align}

Does the statement "choosing $h$ and $\tilde{h}$ sufficiently small  " refer to the line "$h$ and $\tilde{h}$ are both less than $\frac{\delta e^{-CT}}{n}$" ?

I hope this makes any sense. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not surprised that you're perplexed by this -- it was very poorly stated. The sentence

> Since the expression on the right can be made as small as desired by choosing $h$ and
> $\tilde  h$ sufficiently small, this shows ...

should be replaced by

> Thus the expression on the left can be made as small as desired by choosing $h$ and $\tilde h$
> sufficiently small. This shows ...

And you're right, the "sufficiently small" just refers to the stipulation that $|h|$ and $|\tilde h|$ are both less than $\delta e^{-CT}/n$.

I've added a correction to my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Books/ISM/).

Comment: I am afraid that I am still am struggling a bit. I guess it is a bit picky, but I am looking for something like $\Delta_{h}(t,x)-\Delta_{\tilde{h}}(t,x)< \epsilon$. Is what I suggested a valid way to get that?

Comment: It's just a matter of rescaling $\varepsilon$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, you can let $\varepsilon_1 = E\varepsilon /\big(2n e^{CT}(e^{ET}-1)\big)$, and then carry out the whole argument with $\varepsilon_1$ in place of $\varepsilon$. In the end, you get the estimate you're looking for. (This is a very common shortcut in arguments like this, to avoid introducing too many extra symbols.)

Comment: Okay. Then I suppose I wasn't to far off after all.Now things are a lot clearer! Thank you! Is there a book or something that summarises the most common of those little tricks and short cuts, because sometimes I wonder whether I am missing something profound or if I am just not aware of one of those short cuts or conventions.